# Convert set of images to video slide show in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, api

I know there are many such question on the web related to the question I'm asking.

But I'm asking this question because i didn't find anything helpful with the available content.

I want to convert the set of images into a video slide show with some text on each slide using `MVC C#`

The only help i got is http://splicer.codeplex.com

But it doesn't have documentation, so it'd be risky to get start with such api which doesn't have documentation available.

Can anyone suggest how i can do this? If there is any paid `api` which provide such functionality i can use that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ffmpeg. There are some libraries for it on nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=ffmpeg.
Also you can write your own wrapper for it. It's free to use and has many docs.